# Accessing dictionary values within a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary `velocity`.

`velocity = {"x": ({"mag": 5}, {"dir", 1}), "y": ({"mag": 5}, {"dir", 1})}`

I'm trying to access the values of `"mag"` and `"dir"` within `"x"`.

This is how I tried to do it:

`self.position["x"] += ( self.velocity["x"]["mag"] * self.velocity["x"]["dir"] )`

How should I do this?

Comment: That's not a dictionary in a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you may want to define velocity as:

```
velocity = {"x":{"mag": 5, "dir": 1}, "y": {"mag": 5, "dir": 1} }
```

That way, your assignment statement will work:

```
position["x"] += ( velocity["x"]["mag"] * velocity["x"]["dir"] )
```

Answer (score 1):

The values of the `x` and `y` keys are tuples, not dicts, so you need to use tuple indexing to access them:

```
>>> velocity['x'][0]['mag']
5
```

So, your assignment should be:

```
self.position["x"] += ( self.velocity["x"][0]["mag"] * self.velocity["x"][0]["dir"] )
```

To make it more straightforward, make `velocity` a dict of dicts:

```
{'x': {'mag': 5, 'dir': 1}, 'y': {'mag': 5, 'dir': 1}}
```